# why this src tag can't load image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

[This is my react project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFRkp.png)

In `navbar.js` I have brand image that fails to load from `Assets/images` directory.

```
import '../../Assets/Css/Navbar.css';
import image from '../../Assets/Images/andarjani.png'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import {RiHome4Line}  from "react-icons/ri";


export default function Header() {
    return (
            <Navbar bg='dark'>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand  >
                    <img src="../../Assets/Images/andarjani.png" alt='logo' />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <RiHome4Line/>
                    </Nav.Item>
                </Nav>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
    )
}
```

I have problem with this relative path that cant load image.

What should be the correct path?

Comment: place the image in a "public/static" folder and use an absolute path to it. `src` attributes can only make resource requests on runtime while your build system can bundle your files on build time. If you share what bundler/build system you use a link to documentation can be provided.

Comment: What is your build process? Are the styles loaded? What kind of error does the devtools console show? Have you tried another paths?

Comment: can you share your folder structure to that image

Comment: The path seems right. Can you try <img src={image} alt="logo" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** First make sure you are importing the image from the correct folder path. Then try any one of the following methods

**Method 1**

You can either add the image by replacing the image url with `image` as it has been imported

```
import '../../Assets/Css/Navbar.css';
import image from '../../Assets/Images/andarjani.png';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import {RiHome4Line}  from "react-icons/ri";


export default function Header() {
    return (
            <Navbar bg='dark'>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand  >
                    <img src={image} alt='logo' />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <RiHome4Line/>
                    </Nav.Item>
                </Nav>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
    )
}
```

**Method 2**

Or you can add `require("image_url")` instead

```
import '../../Assets/Css/Navbar.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import {RiHome4Line}  from "react-icons/ri";


export default function Header() {
    return (
            <Navbar bg='dark'>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand  >
                    <img src={require('../../Assets/Images/andarjani.png')} alt='logo' />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <RiHome4Line/>
                    </Nav.Item>
                </Nav>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
    )
}
```